# Draw line chart on Google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How can I draw a google line chart on a google map.

I know I can draw lines between gps coordinates (lat/lon) but how can I draw an elevated line with a height and change the view on it ?

For example, If I have few values 10,12,13,12,10 and each value is associated with latitude/longitude value.

How can I plot these points on a map where the value will be the elevation or height of that point?

Something like this
[image]
[image]
Thanks

Comment: [This is what I have seen before](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_elevation-profile_distance.html)

Comment: Thanks... This is another way of showing the data but graphically its good... I want to show the line chart on the map and this has been done http://www.xibis.com/news-and-insight/xibis-adds-3d-data-to-google-maps

Comment: just need some help to get started...

Comment: Well... interesting. I wish you good luck. That sounds like not an easy task. The link you posted mentions *If you'd like more information please contact us*. It might be worth trying :-)

Comment: I have tried it already and information is about the price of the library... :) I want to try it myself first, if its too difficult I will buy the library